# GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() doesn't work

Tags: url, gwt, request

I have problem with my app written in gwt and deployed on tomcat 7. The problem is that I couldn't get base url trough GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() method. I build next request:

```
new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "login");
```

but the result is 404 not found. The application is running in my url: 192.168.3.3:8080/myapp/
When I chenge the tomcat root context of my app to "/" than: 192.168.3.3:8080/ works fine, so I need to get "myapp" from url. Have anyone some ide how to get this part of url? I don't want to put it as literal to request builder.

Comment: If you found the solution for this from the below answers, accept and upvote the answers. If you got your own answer, put that down and accept it. This will help other users who are looking answers for similar type of questions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use,
           GWT.getModuleBaseUrl();
It will return you the complete url your are looking for, i.e, 192.168.3.3:8080/myapp/. If you just want the module name above approach suggested by Jamshid Asatillayev would just work fine, i.e., 
     GWT.getModuleName();

Answer (score 0):

> so I need to get "myapp" from url

Use   [GWT.getModuleName()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html#getModuleName%28%29)   which gets the name of the running module.